# I was wondering if anyone could help me identify this rock

Tags: geology, rocks

I found this rock along with a few other very similar ones. I found it on an island in Croatia.I was wondering if anyone could tell me the name of the rock.
[image: It appears to be a mineral of some sort]

Comment: Welcome to earthscience.stackexchange. Here's [A guide for asking “Identify this rock” questions](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions)

Comment: Crystal shape looks like calcite. Could also be dolomite. My third guess would be some kind of zeolite.